# Solving an ODE with exponentials of the dependent variable

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following equation to solve, I think is just the case of founding a suitable change of variables, but I couldn't think of anything: $$y'' + (y')^2 = 2e^{(-y)}.$$

Any suggestions?

Comment: What about trying $u=e^{-y}$? It'll still be nonlinear but at least it will be polynomial

Comment: It worked. It was a way much simpler substitution than I have thought. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$u=e^y,u'=e^yy',u''=e^yy'^2+e^yy''$$

So the equation reduces to

$$u''=2,u=x^2+ax+b$$
$$e^y=x^2+ax+b$$

Answer (score 8):

Set $u=e^{y}$. Then $y=\log{u}$, and $y'=u'/u$, $y''=u''/u-u'^2/u^2$. Substituting in,
$$ \left( \frac{u''}{u}-\frac{u'^2}{u^2} \right) + \left( \frac{u'}{u} \right)^2 = \frac{2}{u}. $$
Then
$u''=2,$
and no doubt you can carry on easily enough.

Comment: i dont understand why this is downvoted.  i am going to upvote this.

Comment: Well, the RHS should be $2/u$, hence $u'' = 2$. Otherwise, good.